# I've lost rights to edit files in folder etc

Tags: windows, hosts, acl, file-permissions

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

I'm updating the hosts file on regular basis but suddenly it stopped working and now asks for admin rights even though I am administrator.

I've modified and given myself all rights on **hosts** file but the problem seems to be on the 
parent folder **etc**

What happened since I cannot edit (as administrator) hosts any longer and how do I fix it?

Security settings on etc is

```
Group:
CREATOR OWNER
SYSTEM
Administrators (local\Administrator)
Users (Local\Users)
TrustedInstaller
```

Trying to change Rights on advanced security settings I cannot add, edit or remove any rights.

Comment: Have you tried taking ownership of the etc folder and all files?

Comment: it's c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts - is it wise to take ownership of system folder?

Comment: The only time I had trouble edit it was after Spybot Search & Destroy put a read-only attribute on it for security.  Maybe something without your knowing put the read-only attribute on.

Comment: @Scott, the TrustedInstaller has taken over the etc folder

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this on a Windows 7 machine. The only way I've found to resolve this is to use a built-in local administrator account to edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read everyone says to stop the Windows Modules Installer service.

On my machines this service is set to Manual and is stopped.  However, my ACL for hosts file doesn't include TrustedInstaller.  My machines is up to date with patches, so I assume it is configured properly as far as services & ACLs are concerned.

This website http://www.exe-error-fixes.com/disable-trustedinstallerexe/ says this is a Vista pre-SP1 bug.  I assume you have SP2 installed, so this must be a different problem.